# How to generate a random variable by composition?

Tags: random-variables

If I want to generate a random variable with such a pdf: $f(x) = \dfrac 3 {2}x^2 : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$ by composition, what should I do?

I think I can divide the pdf by $x=0$ into two parts. But the $f(x)$ of the new two parts are the same and the CDF of the left part can be a negitive value. 
But I have to use composition for its my homework.
How can I do?

Comment: Compute cdf $F$, generate a standard uniform $U$ and output $F^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: I know that inverse transform method. But the homework says i have to use composition to do that.

Comment: It's unclear what "composition" means in this case. You could first generate $|x|$ and then flip a coin to determine the sign of $x$.

Comment: Composition is also a method to generate random variates.

Comment: How can I do?？？